# Reporte con Gráficos VB6 - APi REST

Tags: sql-server, api, vb6

estimad@s, les traigo una consulta que me está dando vueltas y no se como afrontarla. El sistema propio de la empresa está diseñado en `VB6` (claramente, no lo van a migrar ni lo actualizarán, pero ese es otro tema). La cuestión que surge es que hay muchos, muchos reportes hechos con `CR10` con gráficos. Solo las `PC` con `CR` instalado, pueden ver esos reportes. El problema está en una que otra `dll` que bueno, no viene al caso pero es para ponerlos al tanto. Quisiera saber, probablemente cierren esta pregunta, ¿Cómo puedo encarar para hacer lo siguiente:?

-Quiero abrir -desde un botón en un formulario de VB6- [en Chrome/Firefox/Edge (cualquier navegador)] reportes (que reciban parámetros) que muestren gráficos de barras/torta/etc

A modo de ejemplo:

> -Yo, usuario random, selecciono -desde la pantalla de vb6- un item desde un ComboBox con el año 2023, con un item pais argentina de otro combobox. Ahora, presiono el botón cargar y este debe abrirme en cualquier navegador un reporte con gráficos con datos de SQL de personas que hayan nacido en el 2023 y que sean de argentina separados por sexo masculino o femenino

Entiendo que puedo crear gráficos con librerías de `JS` como `Chart.js` pero, ¿Es posible crear una api que consuma recursos/tablas de SQL, que reciba parámetros desde VB6 y los muestre en el navegador con gráficos?
De ser así, ¿Cómo puedo afrontarlo? Un ejemplo, sería fabuloso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

según lo veo yo, y suponiendo que he entendido bien la pregunta, necesitas realizar varias cosas en distintos lugares. Suponiendo que domines todas ellas te lo resumiré un poco por encima. Hace muchísimo que no toco nada en VB6... si no recuerdo mal es como del 96 del siglo pasado!! Tómate lo que te comento a modo orientativo y si ves que te puede valer pero necesitas algo más en profundidad avisa y veo que puedo hacer...

Al lío...

Partiendo de la base de que tienes acceso al código fuente de VB6 y puedas agregarle cosas al programa...

Aunque suene algo obvio... El ejecutable en VB6 necesita tener un componente que muestre a modo de iframe la página web donde se procesará los datos que le pases en la url desde vb6 y te muestre el reporte, ahí ya le metes chart.js o lo que gustes para que se vea como quieras.

Como digo, si esto te hace sonar la campanita lo miramos más en profundidad.

Comment: Pues, en cuánto a tecnologías me llevo un poco bien con las básicas. Es decir, SQL bien - C# para crear la API (nunca hice una) y VB6 desde donde se debería consumir la API para ver el reporte. Destaco que jamás usé chart.js (en realidad nunca hice nada con gráficos en la web). Es decir, no tengo idea de como hacer gráficos en la web ni como hacer una api. Pero, con el resto creo que andaría bien.

Comment: Hola Trystan, bienvenido, gracias por tu interes, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Bueno, hay mil formas de hacer una api, con que manejes el lenguaje propio del servidor basta, un pequeño script en php que te devuelva un objeto json que puedes luego procesar en donde quieras, VB6 incluido, aunque en este último, de manera rudimentaria, pero bueno... es lo que tiene tener que usar un programa de la prehistoria ^_^ lo que necesitas es demasiado específico para desgranarlo en este post, y como habrás podido imaginar, apenas entro a stack de higos a brevas. Siéntete libre de contactarme y lo vemos con calma, te puedo pasar algún código que otro que podrás usar y tal.